# How to insert into a nested list/association?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, associations, insert

Considering following nested structure:

```
ls = {"a" -> 1,
      "b" -> 2,
      "c" -> {"AA" -> <|"Aaaa" -> <|"yi" -> 512, "h"  -> 45           |>, 
                           "V" -> <|"e2" ->   5, "rr" -> <|"e"->3.14|>|>|>,
              "VV" -> <|  "e4" -> 123|>}}
```

I want to update `"e4"` key to have `124` value instead of `123`.

I can easily extract the value by `"VV" /. ("c" /. ls)`. I can even update the value as follows:

```
Insert["VV" /. ("c" /. ls), "e4" -> 124, -1]
```

This nohow affects the `ls`.

What is the correct way to update the value exactly in `ls`?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to work with this mixed form?

Comment: If you mean the mix of lists and associations, then yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Part` to be able to change list elements. For a list of rules you can use this index finder:

```
RulesIndex[ls_List, keys_List] := 
  Sequence @@ 
   Flatten@FoldPairList[
     With[{pos = 
         FirstPosition[#1, #2 -> _, Missing@"NotFound", 1]~Append~
          2}, {pos, Extract[#1, pos]}] &, ls, keys];

ls[[RulesIndex[ls, {"c", "VV"}]]][["e4"]] = 124
```

which is the same as

```
ls[[3, 2, 2, 2, "e4"]] = 124
```